# How to make height of the body 100% all the time

Tags: html, css

Here is the photo of the border of the body
[image]

As you can see the body is not at 100% height.
Here's the CSS codes of the HTML and Body

```
        html{
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
        body{
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100vh;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            min-width: 400px;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            border: 5px solid black;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
```

I tried putting the height of the html and body separately but it still didn't work. I tried searching and them saying make min-height and height at 100% or 100vh and so I did but it still didn't work. I think it is because those things that are over the body are overflowing from its container?

Edit: I forgot to add this but the reason why I want body to extend along with the overflow is because that left and right container is positioned as sticky. So I can't use **overflow: hidden;**

I can try putting the left and right container as **position: fixed;** but it does not take space so I have to resize everything and also I want to know what is happening so I can avoid this problem.

Here's the whole code
https://codepen.io/n01knowz/pen/qBpBapV
I'm new to CSS so I don't know if there's any writing problem there so please tell me what I can fix.

Update: Okay so the reason the body wasn't extending was because the container is overflowing and technically isn't getting any bigger and so the body isn't expanding because its child's height isn't expanding too. So that's the danger of using when you set the height of the container.

Solution: Just let the container's height be and let the child components of the container be the one to decide its height.

Comment: do you have live url for this ?

Comment: Try `overflow: hidden` for your body.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the overflow attribute. Which can work more than one way.
If you want no scroll bar use hidden, if you want to keep the content you can use scroll.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden; /*any content that would overflow would be hidden and there is no scroll bar, NOTE, this will not stop the containers from overflowing. */
  overflow: scroll; /* this would place scroll bar once the content overflows */
  overflow: auto; /*will only add the scroll bar only after content over flows but will not add if it the content does not overflow */
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to use position sticky here. Problem is that the position of the left and right container are connected to body so they will stop at the border. I want to show the overflow and make the height of the body adjust to the height of the overflow. I should add that to the question.